# Is it possible to call GET in a Capybara/Rspec integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have a Rails 4.2 application....I was adding [content compression via this thoughtbot blog post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/content-compression-with-rack-deflater), but I get an error such as:

```
undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Compression:0x00000009aa4cc8>
```

Perusing over the capybara docs, it seems like you shouldn't be using get.  Any idea how to test the below then in Rails 4?

```
# spec/integration/compression_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'Compression' do
  scenario "a visitor has a browser that supports compression" do
    ['deflate','gzip', 'deflate,gzip','gzip,deflate'].each do|compression_method|
      get root_path, {}, {'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => compression_method }
      response.headers['Content-Encoding'].should be
    end
  end

  scenario "a visitor's browser does not support compression" do
    get root_path
    response.headers['Content-Encoding'].should_not be
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In a capybara test you would use `visit` not `get` ([as described here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#the-dsl)), but that answer won't actually help you because the test you've written above is not an integration test, it's a controller test.

Move it to `spec/controllers` and use the controller-specific helpers describe/context/it etc. to construct your tests for your controller. You can set the headers and do the sorts of checks that you're doing in the code you're showing.